# Why i can't get variable name from Django

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project that i'm working on. I need to print something to CLI to make it easier to debug.

This is what i need

```
print('============================================')
print('VARIABLE_NAME_IN_CAPS')
print(variable)
print(f'LENGTH : {len(variable)}')
print('============================================')
```

this is my function to get variable name. [This](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-get-variable-name-as-string) is where i got the snippet

```
def get_variable_name(variable):
    globals_dict = globals()

    return [var_name for var_name in globals_dict if globals_dict[var_name] is variable]
```

But when i called the function i get empty array `[]`. I've tried to do it without function and do a separate test in another file and it worked. Is there anything that prevent this to happen in Django ?

Comment: Have you tried changing `is` to `==`?

Comment: it throws an error `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

Comment: This confuses me.

Comment: Do you really need `globals`? It does not sound as a good practice. If you need to check if something is working, you should probably do it in apps.YourAppConfig.ready() function. What do you keep in `globals()`?

Comment: `print(f"{variable=}")` will print the variable name, followed by an equal sign, followed by its value. You'd only be missing having it in upper case (all the better, for camelCase like names) and it's length (which isn't relevant, even an error, for numbers or booleans; and when using your helper function, this would always be 1).

Comment: @NixonSparrow because i thought it store all variables in a file, so i think it's a good idea to use `globals`

Comment: @9769953 it prints something like this `variable=array([[1.00000000e+00],[9.91716981e-04],
[1.00000000e+00],
......]`

Comment: So your variable is called "variable". I'm not sure if there is a question in your comment, or that it's just a note.

Comment: no, i mean it prints something like that, my variable is called `arr_list`

Comment: So it would print `arr_list=array([[...`: you get the name and the value.

Comment: What has this got to do with Django? Also needing to find out a variable name from it's value most likely means you aren't using proper data structures for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

In Django you should not use `globals()` unless it's really needed. Instead use environment variables that can be set in settings.py and imported from there or import from file directly in the function (if the file may change - read it while executing).

[How to use env files in Django](https://alicecampkin.medium.com/how-to-set-up-environment-variables-in-django-f3c4db78c55f)